# install rpm package using chef

Tags: ruby, linux, rpm, chef-recipe

I am newbie to `Chef` and trying to install an `rpm package` in `CentOS vm`. I get this error when I run the `action: install command`. Looked at the `logs` and seems like an `access issue` though I am running  as `root user`. Log states `block in action-install` etc. Not sure what it means, `may be related to permission?`

I can run `rpm -ivh --nodeps package-name` and it works fine.

If I run my `Chef recipe` it throw error. 
This is recipe code:

```
package "package-name.rpm" do
source "/package-name.rpm"
action :install
end
```

I run using `chef-client --local-mode --runlist package-name` so it runs against `local-repo` and not `yum`.

This is my log:

```
Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[package-name.rpm] (package-name::default line 15) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec:  returned 1, expected 0
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:158:in `handle_command_failures'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1021:in `yum_command'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb:1106:in `install_package'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:82:in `block in action_install'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:156:in `converge_by'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:80:in `action_install'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:121:in `run_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource.rb:648:in `run_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:237:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:34:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:34:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Etan Thanks for the edit. I couldn't figure how to format the log file

Comment: Fixed it. It was a dependency issue.

Answer (score -1):

rpm_package 'package_name' do 
action :install
end

Comment: It would be good to give an overview of what you are trying to do instead of only posting the command